# What's a good framework for managing flashdata in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, frameworks

I'm looking for a framework to manage flashdata on google app engine. Flashdata is data that only lives from one page to another, so for example, a user fills out a form, this form gets processed in the post method of a handler, and is redirected to a get handler, as specified with the post redirect get pattern. On the get page, I'd like to show some data, set in the post page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify a runtime, so I'm going to assume Python.

webapp2 [features session support](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html), including support for flash messages.